# API not working when I call it on my services but works when I type it on my browser (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Help me, I've been stuck with those for 2 days now and I cant figure out why the code is not working. My **API** code for getting the attendance seems to be working but it doesn't work when I call it on my services

What I am trying to do here is filter the facschedList where if there is already and attendance recorded it will be removed from the list of faculty schedules.

**Here is the code on my api for getting the Faculty Schedules:**

```
List<FacultySchedule> facsched = db.FacultySchedules.Where(q => q.Day.Contains(day)).ToList(); // GET ALL SCHED DEPENDING ON CURRENT DAY OF THE WEEK

        foreach (var sched in facsched)
        {
            DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sched.Time_from);
            DateTime dismissalTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sched.Time_to);

            if (dt >= startTime && dt <= dismissalTime)
            {
                facschedlist.Add(sched);
            }
        }
        return Ok(facschedlist);
```

**Here is my Services:**

```
 public async Task<List<FacultySchedule>> GetFacultySched()
    {
        RestClient<FacultySchedule> restClient = new RestClient<FacultySchedule>();

        List<FacultySchedule> facschedList = await restClient.GetFacSchedulebyTimeAsync();

        foreach (var f in facschedList)
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time.Replace("UTC", "+08:00"), "HH:mm", null);

            Attendance existingAttendance = await GetAttendance(f.SchedID);

            if (existingAttendance != null)
            {
               facschedList.Remove(f);
            }
        }
        return facschedList;
    }
```

Here is the code in the api to get the attendance:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Date;

        Attendance attendance = await db.Attendances.FirstAsync(q => q.SchedID.Equals(schedid)
        && q.DateChecked.Year == dt.Year
        && q.DateChecked.Month == dt.Month
        && q.DateChecked.Day == dt.Day);
```

Comment: "Not working" means what exactly? Also what is `RestClient`?

Comment: It not retrieving the Attendance that will filter the FacultySchedule.  The restclient is a plugin where it converts my models  to json and sent to my api controller.

Comment: Have you ruled out connectivity issues?  Have you confirmed that the request is reaching your backend and being executed successfully?

Comment: yes. everything works fine but it just ignores the code for getting the attendance. but i checked my api and it works